# safely storing information about in-app purchases being purchased

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, persistence, data-storage

What is the best way to store information about in-app purchases being purchased? With information I mean strings, Bool values..nothing fancy. No need to be highly hacker proof, because of low budget. I just need to hide that information and persist it during app launches. I heard that `NSUserDefaults` is bad for this..what about writing files to `DocumentDirectory`? I would like to hide that file with IAP information from user or make in encrypted and..why not just both?

Comment: I normally store it in the keychain. There are a few Keychain wrapper frameworks that make it easier  if you search cocoapods.org